# How to solve expo-document-picker warning about appleTeamId

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

When using EAS to build an iOS app that uses expo-document-picker, I get the following warning:

> expo-document-picker: Cannot configure iOS entitlements because neither the appleTeamId property, nor the environment variable EXPO_APPLE_TEAM_ID were defined

I searched for more information about this but I found nothing. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 5):

[This document](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-document-picker#plugin) explains it. For EAS Managed builds, you need to configure the expo-document-picker in app.json and include your Apple team ID:

```json
{
  "ios": {
    "usesIcloudStorage": true,
    "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourname.yourapp"
  },
  "plugins": [
    [
      "expo-document-picker",
      {
        "appleTeamId": "YOUR_TEAM_ID"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```